# Hamburger icon doesn't animate with AppCompat library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I'm using the appcompat-v7 library to backport the Lollipop Toolbar. It looks correct, but it does not animate when I click the hamburger icon (it stays a hamburger icon). What's strange is that if I open the drawer and rotate the device, the hamburger icon changes to an arrow like it should had already been prior to rotating. If I rotate back to portrait, it stays an arrow. Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_navigation);

    mDrawerLayout = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.drawer_layout);
    mContentFrameLayout = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.content);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_menu, R.string.close_menu);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And my theme:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line: `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);`

The `DrawerListener` has a method called `onDrawerSlide()`. That is where the animation is triggered, and it is handled by the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object. Switch out that line with this:

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`

If you need to listen for events on the drawer, you can override them on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_menu, R.string.close_menu) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
    }
};
```

Be sure to call through to the `super` implementation.